# Nginx, three identical vhost configs, one works, the other two got too many redirects

Tags: nginx, centos, redirect, certbot

I got three websites on my server. My mainpage gamenotify.net works well. My other two are getting to many redirects between www and non-www url. My vhost files are identical to my mainpage. I just copied it and replaced the folder names and webpage names.

My main page conf file

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl http2;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             www.gamenotify.net;
    set                     $base path/nginx/sites;
    root                    $base/gamenotify;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate         path/gamenotify.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     path/gamenotify.net/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate path/gamenotify.net/chain.pem;

    # HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    # security
    include                 nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # index.php
    index                   index.php;

    # index.php fallback
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
    include nginxconfig.io/gamenotify.net.wordpress.conf;

    # handle .php
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        include      nginxconfig.io/php_fastcgi.conf;
    }
}

# non-www, subdomains redirect
server {
    listen                  443 ssl http2;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             .gamenotify.net;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate         path/gamenotify.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     path/gamenotify.net/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate path/gamenotify.net/chain.pem;
    return                  301 https://www.gamenotify.net$request_uri;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name .gamenotify.net;
    include     nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.gamenotify.net$request_uri;
    }
}
```

My wordpress config is only to hide certain files and folders.

In comparison my second page config file

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl http2;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             www.fotobox-mettingen.de;
    set                     $base path/nginx/sites;
    root                    $base/fotobox;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate         path/fotobox-mettingen.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     path/fotobox-mettingen.de/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate path/fotobox-mettingen.de/chain.pem;

    # HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    # security
    include                 nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # index.php
    index                   index.php;
    
    # index.php fallback
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
    include nginxconfig.io/fotobox-mettingen.de.wordpress.conf;

    # handle .php
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        include      nginxconfig.io/php_fastcgi.conf;
   }
}

# non-www, subdomains redirect
server {
    listen                  443 ssl http2;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             .fotobox-mettingen.de;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate         path/fotobox-mettingen.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     path/fotobox-mettingen.de/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate path/fotobox-mettingen.de/chain.pem;
    return                  301 https://www.fotobox-mettingen.de$request_uri;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name .fotobox-mettingen.de;
    include     nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.fotobox-mettingen.de$request_uri;
    }
}
```

My third page got the same config and the same error. Only my first page works well.
Now where is my error on my second config? Why do i get so too many redirects?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use `curl -I` on the website causing too many redirects to identify the response headers. You will be able to see if the redirect is originating from Nginx or PHP.

Comment: with `curl -I` i get the info `x-redirect-by: WordPress`. So i think my wordpress setup is the problem. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found my problem. Kudos are going to Richard. My problem was a wrong configuration with wordpress. So i got my endless loop.

Had to change some entries for the website title and url in the database.

Thank you <3